# How to round a float number in Java if its a whole?

Tags: java, rounding

How do I round a float number if it returns a whole value? And, how do I round if it's like:
`5/2 = 2.5` 
and NOT like this:
`5/2 = 2.50000000`

Answer (score 4):

A `double` does not allow you to specify the number of decimal places it has; you may be able to set as many as you wish to 0, but they are still there.  (Note that, mathematically, the two values you show for 5/2 are the same.)  What you *can* do is control how many get *displayed*; since you haven't specified how you are attempting to display this value, I can't help in how to modify it to limit the number of decimal places to show.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever needed, you can make some modifications on your double, such as using the `setRoundingMode` method of [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setRoundingMode%28java.math.RoundingMode%29) class, along with the [RoundingMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) enum.

As mentioned before though, `2.5` is the same with `2.500000` in a `double`, you do not have to change its digits.

I guess you are trying to print your double and you get a number of unwanted digits in the output. In that case, I suggest though that you convert your double into a formatted string and use it as such:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", myDouble));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are a bit confused I think...
2.5 and 2.50000000 are the **exact** same thing!
They are just written differently.

I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve but you can round floats like this:

```
float result = Math.round(someFloat);
```

If you always want to round up or down regardless of what the number is use:

```
float result = (float)Math.ceil(someFloat);
```

or

```
float result = (float)Math.floor(someFloat);
```